# Eigenvalue of $A-aI_3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Question: Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}  a+1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & a+1 & 1 \\  1 & 1 & a+1\end{pmatrix}$. Show that $A-aI_3$ has eigenvalue of 3. Also find eigenvector.

My thinking:

I know that we have to apply characteristic polynomial $|A- \lambda I|$ to find the eigenvalue. I don't understand the part $A-aI_3$. What should I suppose to do here with this $A-aI_3$ ? I am kinda confused. Your kind suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: $A-aI$ is just a matrix of ones. You need to find any vector $v$ such that $(A-aI)v = 3v$. Try $(1,1,1)^T$.

Comment: How can I find eigen value without computing  $det(A-aI)$? In this case, $det=0$. I am still confused.

Comment: To find the eigenvalues you need to find the values of $t$ for which there is some non zero $v$ such that $(A-aI)v = t v$. You can do this by inspection or computing the characteristic polynomial of $\det (A-aI-tI)$.

Comment: @copper.hat I got for $\lambda=0, x_1+x_2+x_3=0$ and for $\lambda=3$ , I got lienar system with zero rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative answer:  $A-aI_3=\begin{pmatrix}  1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\  1 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ clearly has eigenvalue $0$

with independent eigenvectors $\begin{pmatrix}  1  \\ -1  \\  0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}  1  \\ 0  \\  -1 \end{pmatrix}.$

The sum of the eigenvalues is the trace of the matrix, which is $3$, so the other eigenvalue is $3$.

An eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $3$ is in the kernel of  $\begin{pmatrix}  -2 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -2 & 1 \\  1 & 1 & -2\end{pmatrix}$ , i.e. $(-2,1,1)\times(1,-2,1)=(-3,-3,-3)$.

Answer (score 2):

$A-aI_3=\begin{pmatrix}  1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\  1 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$.

What is $\begin{pmatrix}  1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\  1 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}  1  \\ 1  \\  1 \end{pmatrix}?$

Comment: alternative approach:  the sum of the eigenvalues of $A-aI_3$ is its trace, which is $3$, and $\begin{pmatrix}  1  \\ -1\\  0 \end{pmatrix} $ and$ \begin{pmatrix}  1  \\ 0\\  -1 \end{pmatrix} $ are eigenvectors with eigenvalue $0$

Comment: I got the same thing! How to find then eigen value and eigen vector?

Comment: What is $\begin{pmatrix}  1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\  1 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}  1  \\ 1  \\  1 \end{pmatrix}?$  $A\overrightarrow  v=\lambda   \overrightarrow v$ and $\overrightarrow v\ne\overrightarrow0$ means $\overrightarrow v$ is eigenvector, $a$ is eigenvalue

Comment: I guess, I am something of this interesting problem!

Comment: In my previous comment, I meant $\lambda$ is eigenvalue

Comment: Tanner, How did you get eigen vectors? I have for $\lemda =0, x_1+x_2+x_3=0$, For $\lamda =3, I got linear system with zero rows!

Comment: $\begin{pmatrix}  1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\  1 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}  x  \\ y \\  z \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}  x+y+z  \\ x+y+z \\  x+y+z \end{pmatrix}=\lambda \begin{pmatrix}  x  \\ y \\  z \end{pmatrix}\implies x+y+z=\lambda x=\lambda y=\lambda z\implies x=y=z$ or $(\lambda=0$ and $x+y+z=0)$

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $A-aI$ is the matrix with just ones. So $(A-aI)(1,1,1) = 3(1,1,1)$

Answer (score 0):

Another ad hoc alternative:

Note that $B=A-aI = e e^T$, where$e$ is a vector of ones.

To solve $B v = t v$, we note that ${\cal R B} = \operatorname{sp} \{ e \}$, so
the only non zero eigenvalue of $B$ can be found by solving
$e e^T e = t e$, so get $t=e^T e = 3$.

Since $\dim {R B} = 1$, we see that $\dim \ker B = 2$ and so $B$ has two zero eigenvalues (meaning there are two linearly independent $v_1,v_2$ such that
$B v_1 = 0, B v_2 = 0$.

Since $\ker B = \ker e^T$, we can find two suitable $v_k$ by solving $e^T v = 0$.